# IntelliJ-Scala format list elements same line when using ::

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, formatting

when building a nested object which gets a list as its imputs using `::` for building the list the auto-format is misleading:

```
   val sentimentExpectedSchema = StructType(
        StructField("metadata", StructType(
          StructField("type", StringType, nullable = false) :: 
            StructField("job_run_time", LongType, nullable = false) ::
            StructField("version", LongType, nullable = false) :: Nil
        )) :: Nil
      )
```

**Someone new to the code will have the first impression that `job_run_time` is nested to `type`, which is not true.**

I would expect the following format-rule to be used:

```
   val sentimentExpectedSchema = StructType(
        StructField("metadata", StructType(
          StructField("type", StringType, nullable = false) :: 
          StructField("job_run_time", LongType, nullable = false) ::
          StructField("version", LongType, nullable = false) :: Nil
        )) :: Nil
      )
```

**In this way, it is pretty much obvious that `job_run_time` and `type` are in the same nesting level.**

Furthermore, if one builds the `Array/List` "normally", it will be properly formated:

```
      val sentimentExpectedSchema = StructType(Array(
        StructField("metadata", StructType(Array(
          StructField("type", StringType, nullable = false),
          StructField("job_run_time", LongType, nullable = false),
          StructField("version", LongType, nullable = false)
        )))
      ))
```

**Is there a way to customize my IntelliJ configuration to properly format lists built using `::` as it formats with `Array()/List()`?**

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that you will be able to always force new line on `:: Nil` and always having all of `first :: second :: third :: Nil` aligned to the same column - `::` is just infix, aside from the fact that methods ending with `:` have reverse order in infix notation, is nothing special about it from the language point of view. It will always be indented same way as if it was `x.call(y).call(z)`, the first element having one less indent as the following chains.

However, you can experiment with adding [scalafmt](https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/) to your project and trying out various [`newlines.` config options](https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/docs/configuration.html#newlines) to see which one would be unambiguous enough for you.

An example config could look like:

```
// put into .scalafmt.conf in the root of your project
version = 2.6.3
align = most
trailingCommas = preserve
maxColumn = 120

newlines.afterInfix = many,keep
newlines.afterInfixBreakOnNested = true
```

Try out some options and see which one works best for you. Using the formatting I have in my current project I got:

```
val sentimentExpectedSchema = StructType(
  StructField(
    "metadata",
    StructType(
      StructField("type", StringType, nullable = false) ::
        StructField("job_run_time", LongType, nullable = false) ::
        StructField("version", LongType, nullable = false) :: Nil
    )
  ) :: Nil
)
```

which should be enough to not cause the *false impression that `job_run_time` is nested to `type`*. At least by my and other people used to this style - chain of `::` is nested deeper than `StructType` which contains them, and each line is short enough to see that it end with `::`. If it was too long to see this `::` it would be broken down, with more indentations for nested elements.

(As a bonus, this config will be automatically imported by IntelliJ so everyone participating in your project will use the same settings. You can also enforce checking this formatting in CI, or during compilation by sbt plugin).

If that still doesn't meet your needs, just embrace the fact that `::` chains are just method chains and will never have the same formatting as varargs, weather you use scalafmt or IntelliJ, so just use `List(x, y, z)` instead. It would actually feel wrong if they did since this is basically a multi-line expression which produces a single value, it should be obvious at a glance where it starts (the less indented line) and where it ends (the last more indented line). If `"job_run_time"` was indeed nested in `"type"`, then `"type"` would have some closing parenthesis aligned to `StructField` AND THEN single indentation more would imply nesting. But there isn't one so it implies that these are just sequences of method calls of a single expression.

TBH I've never seen `a :: b :: c :: Nil` used intensively to construct values in any real prod codebases, since `List(a, b, c)` is always shorter. Only sometimes it made some sense to use `::` instead of `+:` as prepend operation (`val newList = newHead :: oldList`). Obviously, it also makes sense in pattern-matching (`case a :: b :: c :: Nil =>`).

The only real use case when constructing values with `::` is actually needed, that I can think of, is building `HList` with Shapeless (`"x" :: 2 :: 'c' :: HNil`), because you cannot build heterogeneous list type with varargs.

TL;DR - just use `List` or get used to what standard formatters do.